# How can i restart the music

Tags: java, swing, jcheckbox

The background music doesn't restart.

The background music stops when i uncheck the checkbox. but when i check again, music doesn't start again. i try to use getTime() method which i made in the new "Music" class, i don't know how to start from the time which i got.
i saw another questions. They said i have to save "position". but i don't know what it means. sorry.

```
//java on eclipse
private Music introMusic = new Music("introMusic.mp3", true);
private JCheckBox musicOnOff = new JCheckBox("BGM", true);
//
musicOnOff.setBorderPainted(false);
musicOnOff.setContentAreaFilled(false);
musicOnOff.setFocusPainted(false);
musicOnOff.setBounds(462, 334, 100, 100);
musicOnOff.setVisible(true);
musicOnOff.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {
    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent e) {
           if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.DESELECTED) {
               introMusic.close();
           }

           else if(e.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED){
               introMusic.start();

           }
    }

});
add(musicOnOff);
```

i'd like to make the music restart when the Checkbox is checked again. Please help me! Thank you!!

Comment: Where does the `Music` class come from? Does it have a `stop()` or `pause()` method instead of the `close()` method?

Comment: no, i don't code it yet. but i found solution, and i made pause and resume method! Thank you for leave the comment!!